# Conditionally call function A after finishing function B

Tags: python, repeat, function

I have two similar functions function `def A()` and function `def B()` written so far, and it works, but I would like to do it, so that after a user finishes writing data in function `B()`,... he is given an option to either quit, or begin the process again with writing data in function `A()`

So that theoretically, user could repeat the process a million times before he (for example) hits `ENTER` to quit the program.

How would I achieve that?

```
def A(parameters):
    content...
    ...
    ...

def B(parameters):
    content...
    ...
    ...

Press R to repeat with def A (parameters), press Q to quit:
```

Comment: Your design is wrong. Computations and I/O should be as separated as possible. If you mingle them, you'll regret it. If `B` and `A` compute something, perfect, but do *not* call `input`/`raw_input` inside them! You should first obtain the parameters from the user and *then* call `A` or `B`. Note that in this way you can re-use `A` and `B` in other contexts, without modifying their code(that in your case would ask the user for inputs that maybe you do not want in this new situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to merge the functionality of `A()` with `B()` and pass a flag, however here is a solution that allows `A()` to be called after `B()` until the user hits `RETURN`:

```
def A():
    print 'Processing in A!'

def B():

    choice = ''
    print 'Processing in B!'

    while choice.lower().strip() != 'r':    
        choice = raw_input("Press R to repeat, RETURN to exit: ").lower().strip()            
        if choice == '':
            return False
        if choice  == 'r':
            return True

while B():
    A()
```

Output:

```
Processing in B!
Press R to repeat, RETURN to exit: R
Processing in A!
Processing in B!
Press R to repeat, RETURN to exit: r
Processing in A!
Processing in B!
Press R to repeat, RETURN to exit: notR
Press R to repeat, RETURN to exit:
```

Some notes:

`lower()` returns whatever the user types as all lowercase characters allowing `r` and `R` to be treated the same.

`strip()` removes any leading or trailing whitespace from the input.

Comment: Didn't need that  complex code but I managed to create this fine thanx to you THANK YOU

Comment: Argh!!! Why do you use recursion for this? This is a typical case that a `while` can solve.

Comment: That's called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) which, if possible, is even *worse* than recursion because in this situations you make the code ugly *and* inefficient *and* not correct(python will complain after 1000 recursive calls, so if the user provide the wrong input for a sufficient number of times your program does not satisfy the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Bakuriu this is exactly what the OP asked, they did not ask how to repeated call two functions, they asked how to conditionally call one function from another which this code does..

Comment: @sudo_O I do not think the OP's question is so clear about that. He uses the terms "writing data in B()" which does not mean anything. Also he says "*after* the user has finished ..." So Lie Ryan's answer is perfectly correct(even though a bit summarized): B finishes then you can ask the user whatever you want and conditionally start A etc. The OP never states that the A call should be in B. He just says "begin the process again with A". Which again does not mean much. In doubt you should provide the best solution not the worst one. With your solution he'll have *many* more problems later.

Comment: In @Lie Ryan solution `A()` is only conditionally called after `A()` & `B()` have been called not just `B()` so you would process the input with `A()` first not `B()`, which isn't quite what the `OP` asked for. `Recursion`/`Mutual Recursion` aren't bad programming practices in general, the user ins't actually going to hit the `recursion` limit. This is a solution that fits the spec, yes I agree this ins't the way I'd do it.

Comment: @sudo_O That's the point. You should tell the OP "Yeah, you can do this ...nasty solution... but Do not do it! It's wrong! You could instead do some refactoring ...how... and do this ...real solution"

Comment: @Bakuriu you are right, Re-factored solution added without `Mutual Recursion` No getting away from asking to repeat inside `B()` However.

Comment: @sudo_O better! :) I agree that recursion is not inherently bad. There are places where it's clearly the right thing to do. Just not here!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
i = "r"
while i != "q":
    A()
    B()
    i = raw_input("Press Q to quit, press any other key to repeat with def A (parameters):").lower().strip()
```